# Elasticsearch nested aggregations return duplicate value

Tags: elasticsearch

This is data:

```
{
  "search_product_sku" : "FD0044S",
  "price" : 500.00,
  "car_detail" : [
            {
              "car_brand" : "TOYOTA",
              "specification" : "TOYOTA Avanza 1.3L F601 2004"
            },
            {
              "car_brand" : "SUZUKI",
              "specification" : "SUZUKI APV 1.6L GC416X8A 2005"
            }
          ],
}
```

I want to nest `car_detail.specification` inside `car_detail.car_brand`

this is nested aggregation query:

```
GET /my_products/_search
{
  "size": 50, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":[
          {
            "query_string": {
                "query": "*FD0044S*",
                "fields": [ "search_product_sku"]
             }
         }
       ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
            "total_car_brand" : {
                "terms":
                    {
                      "field": "car_detail.car_brand.keyword"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                      "total_car_spec": {
                            "terms": {
                               "field": "car_detail.specification.keyword"
                             }
                          }
                      }
                   }        
                }
             }
```

But the results as you can see **all** `car_detail.specification` are placed inside each  `car_detail.car_brand`

```
"aggregations" : {
    "total_car_brand" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "SUZUKI",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_car_spec" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "SUZUKI APV 1.6L GC416X8A 2005",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "TOYOTA Avanza 1.3L F601 2004",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "TOYOTA",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_car_spec" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "SUZUKI APV 1.6L GC416X8A 2005",
                "doc_count" : 1
              },
              {
                "key" : "TOYOTA Avanza 1.3L F601 2004",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This is a result that I want.

```
"aggregations" : {
    "total_car_brand" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "SUZUKI",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_car_spec" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "SUZUKI APV 1.6L GC416X8A 2005",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "TOYOTA",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_car_spec" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "TOYOTA Avanza 1.3L F601 2004",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Could you show your mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your mapping is but I tested it like this and it worked.

Mapping

```
PUT idx_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "search_product_sku": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "car_detail": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "car_brand": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "specification": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query

```
GET /idx_nested/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "car_detail": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "car_detail"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_car_brand": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "car_detail.car_brand",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_car_spec": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "car_detail.specification"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help . It's work . I'm  newbie for Elasticsearch and I just imported data to elastic and Elastic mapping it automatically.